# How to get host name from ip address or sockaddr_in structure (C++/WinAPI)?

Tags: c++, winapi, sockets, winsock2

How to get host name (like "www.google.com") from ip address or sockaddr_in/sockaddr_in6/sockaddr structure (or another) in C++ (WinAPI)?

Comment: See [`gethostbyaddr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get domain name from Given IP in MFC (VC++)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204174/how-to-get-domain-name-from-given-ip-in-mfc-vc)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that's deprecated in favor of `getnameinfo`.

Comment: Okay, see [`getnameinfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then. :)

Comment: Thanks for quick answer) I used msdn's example for getnameinfo function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It works, but not correct. Example - for ip "173.194.35.183" (google.com.ua) it returns me "muc03s02-in-f23.1e100.net"

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [`getnameinfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Example included on the MSDN page.